# kartik GridView link data tags in ActionColumn

Tags: yii2

I am using [Kartik's GridView](http://demos.krajee.com/grid). I want to show a text in a `DataColumn` that is an external link. The thing is that I need to have pjax activated in the GridView, but disabled for this particular link. My code is the following:

```
[
        'class'=>'\kartik\grid\DataColumn',
        'attribute'=>'idSubject.idnumber',
        'value'=>function($model) {
            return Html::a($model->getIdSubject()->one()->idnumber  ,
                ['/subject/view','id'=>$model->getIdSubject()->one()->id_subject],
                [
                    'data-pjax'=>0
                ]);
        },
        'format'=>'html',
        'filter'=>Html::activeTextInput($searchModel, 'idnumber', ['class'=>'form-control']),
        'label' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
        'vAlign' => 'middle'
],
```

The text link is generated correctly, but without the `data-pjax` tag. I've put a `data-confirm` tag as well, and it is ignored. It seems that all extra tags I specify in the link are ignored. However, if I generate the exact same link in an `ActionColumn`, everything works as expected. Is there a way do add tags to an `Html::a` element in a `DataColumn`?

Answer (score -2):

try to Use

```
[ 'data-pjax' => false ]
```

Comment: I've already tried, but then the column shows the HTML source code

Comment: you can also use for ex : Url::to(['/your-controller/your-action', 'YourSearchModel' => ['somenumber'=> 'ur_value']])

Comment: I have no trouble generating the link, which is to an external url (not the same controller that is displaying the grid). I have problems disabling pjax for that particular link